# Documentation of appropriate use for each logging level in python

Tags: python, logging

I'm having trouble finding an authoritative reference which describes correct usage for each of the five logging levels in Python (`DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARNING`, `ERROR`, `CRITICAL`). The docs are not specifying it:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0282/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Also found a few blogs with some personal opinions, but nothing "official" that could for example serve to settle a difference of opinions.

Is there such a reference out there?

Comment: what sort of guidance do you need, have you seen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog.  the levels are pretty arbitrary in my head, what's useful at each level generally becomes obvious with experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs *do* specify this information. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging). Be sure to read the whole of the section.

Answer (score 0):

Those level are not specific to Python logging but are common to most logging system and originate from Unix syslog. They can be adjusted per application or system, but the common usage is:

- DEBUG: message that should not be used in normal usage but can help to debug the application. Typically milestones in a chained processing to more easily find where an error occurs
- NOTICE: normal messages that should always be present. Typically start and stop of an application or a subsystem
- WARNING: abnormal condition but the processing could continue. Typically space becoming low on a disk device or a function detected incorrect characters in a field but could use a fallback strategy
- ERROR: an operation could not be processed but the application can continue to process other operations. Typically an invalid value was detected and lead to an transaction abort
- CRITICAL: the application cannot continue. Typically the connection to the database was lost and could not be recovered, or a disk cannot be reached...